# GET WebRequest giving the same response as previous call

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method that gets the devices for a certain user. When I run it once for UserA I get the devices for UserA but when I run it again for UserB I get the devices for UserA.

```
Uri url = new Uri("https://stuff.com/otherstuff/api/devices");
HttpWebRequest getrequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
getrequest.Method = "GET";
getrequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + stringaccessToken;
string data = "";
try
{
    using (WebResponse getresponse = await getrequest.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = getresponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                data = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                reader.Close();
            }
            responseStream.Close();
        }
        getresponse.Close();
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    data = ex.Message;
}
textBlock.Text = data;
```

I have a breakpoint at

```
getrequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + stringaccessToken;
```

to get the access token to make sure the user really has changed. (different access token = different user)

When I run the calls on Postman with the access tokens for each user I get the correct devices each time but with my method it only works the first time before getting the same response as the first call.

Comment: Do the headers show any evidence of caching?

Comment: I haven't done anything with the caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got it, I needed to add

```
getrequest.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
```

Setting the Cache-Control fixed my problem.
Thanks Jasen.